# How to extract a numeric value from MQTT topic

Tags: mqtt, c#-3.0

I am new to MQTT. My mqtt topic is given below
hello/receiver/{bookId}/{stId}

book id and stid can be any integer that will be published by client. My target is to subscribe against this topic and fetch the value of bookid and stid. My problem is How can I subscribe against a topic that contains some values that can be changes  in each publishing of message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT supports 2 types of wildcards that can be used in topic patterns when subscribing.

- `+` which matches a single level
- `#` which can match multiple levels (but only at the end of a topic)

E.g. `hello/receive/+/+` will match what you are looking for

`hello/receive/#` will also match, but would also include `hello/receive`, `hello/receive/foo`, `hello/receive/foo/bar`, `hello/receive/foo/bar/baz` and so on.